# .htaccess gets data from table but crashes the page

Tags: php, .htaccess

Please help me with this simple problem. I cant figure out why.
I used the following .htaccess file. It takes details from table but crashes the page.

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^detail/([0-9]+) Details.php?ph=$1 [NC,L]
```

and shows the data from table. but crashes the page.[image]

This is my php Code:

```
        if(array_key_exists('test', $_POST)) {
                    $phone = $_POST['search'];
                    $quer="SELECT * FROM `user_table` ";
                    $result = $conn->prepare($quer);
                    $result->execute();
                    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        if($row){
                    echo " <div class=\"row\"><div class =\"col-lg-8 col-md-8  col-xs-8 col-md-8\">";
                    echo "<table class=\"table table-striped table-hover\">";
                    echo "<thead  class=\"thead-inverse\">";
                    echo "<tr> <th>Name</th><th>Gender</th>  <th>Scan</th> <th>Delivery</th> <th>Product</th></tr>";
                    echo "</thead>";
                    echo "<tbody>";
                        $phone = $row['Phone'];
                        echo "<tr><td>";
                        echo "<a href=\"Details.php?ph=".$phone."\">";
```

Comment: If the page crash, the problem is probably from the PHP code and not from the rewriting rule, please show your php code

Comment: when you say "crashes"...what error message does it give you? Because you screenshot looks like it was successful (apart from the broken image links)

Comment: it is about relative paths in HTML `src` attributes. Make them root-relative or specify a `<base>` tag.